# Rails 4 Devise custom SAML configuration per model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, saml

I'm running Rails 4 with Devise and Devise Saml Authenticatable for my Accounts.

I'd like to have multiple accounts who each use a different SAML IdP to access the site, but am having difficulty separating the saml configurations.

I have a `config.saml_configure do |settings| ...... end` block in my `devise.rb`, but the two models (Employee & Client) have different SAML configurations. Is there a way to have certain devise configs for one model and completely different configurations for another?

Thanks.

Comment: I was never able to figure this out. I resorted to simply using one SAML portal, which is less than ideal but worked well enough.